# Centering map marker on Gmaps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

http://bit.ly/Uzu45r

I've implemented GMAPS V3 and having trouble centering up the marker in #map. If you click on one of the locations in the above link, it goes to the location and does the zoom as it should, however, it doesn't center it up.

How can I have it centered once the user clicks on the location in the address list?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

in your click event listener

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
```

add

```
map.setCenter(marker.getPosition())
```

see a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/RASG/vA4eQ/
(drag the marker to re-center)

Answer (score 0):

`map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());`

I'd also consider making your map a little larger as the info box will be out of view when the map is centered on the marker.

Answer (score 0):

You are centering map OK buth upon opening infowindow iz pans so that it is visible. IMHO you have 2 oprions:
1. after showing infowindow pan to marker position, buth there is possibility that infowindow will be out of viewport.
2. Use Smartinfowindow control

**Include this JS into youre page**

```
http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/smartinfowindow/js/smartinfowindow.js
```

Try to understand source of thise DEMO page (very simple).

```
http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/smartinfowindow/smartinfowindow.html
```

And good luck.

Comment: please use a proper language. avoid these kind of initialisms (IMHO, LOL, etc.). there are lots of people here that are not native english speakers (including myself).

Answer (score 0):

Update your code like

```
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(c_lat,c_lng);
var myOptions = {
    zoom: 2,
    center: myLatLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
};
```

Comment: Thanks - what about the initial lat,lng?

Comment: check my source code please as I have already done this using another variable. Still cannot center when clicking on the other addresses :(

Comment: But map type should have nothing to do with centering, and I can't have it set to terrain.